# Which is the fastest sorting technique to sort large number of text records in Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting

I am using the default sort algorithm in swift. 
But for 10000(10k) records, it takes time of almost 1 minute on ipad.

```
private var fd: [[String:AnyObject]]? = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

Here is my code for Descending

```
self.fd = self.fd!.sort ({ (r1, r2) -> Bool in
let t = self.headers![b.tag - 10]
if r1[t.title] is String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    if dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r1[t.title]!)") != nil {
        let d1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r1[t.title]!)")
        let d2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r2[t.title]!)")
        return d1 > d2
    } else {
        // return "\(r1[t.title])".localizedStandardCompare("\(r2[t.title])") == .OrderedDescending
        return "\(r1[t.title])" > "\(r2[t.title])"
    }
} else if r1[t.title] is Int {
    return Int(String(r1[t.title]!)) > Int(String(r2[t.title]!))
} else {
    // return "\(r1[t.title])".localizedStandardCompare("\(r2[t.title])") == .OrderedDescending
    return "\(r1[t.title])" > "\(r2[t.title])"
}})
```

For Ascending

```
self.fd = self.fd!.sort ({
(r1, r2) -> Bool in
let t = self.headers![b.tag - 10]
if r1[t.title] is String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    if dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r1[t.title]!)") != nil {
        let d1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r1[t.title]!)")
        let d2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("\(r2[t.title]!)")
        return d1 < d2
    } else {
        //return "\(r1[t.title])".localizedStandardCompare("\(r2[t.title])") == .OrderedAscending
        return "\(r1[t.title])" < "\(r2[t.title])"
    }
} else if r1[t.title] is Int {
    return Int(String(r1[t.title]!)) < Int(String(r2[t.title]!))
} else {
    // return "\(r1[t.title])".localizedStandardCompare("\(r2[t.title])") == .OrderedAscending
    return "\(r1[t.title])" < "\(r2[t.title])"
}})
```

Main problem is its taking more than 60 seconds for data larger than 10k.
Please provide me a solution for this.

Comment: `let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter(); dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"` move that OUTSIDE the closure. It's always the same, it's a useless alloc/init and consuming. That should save you a little.

Comment: Have you tried using the Time Profiler tool in instruments? E.g. https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: see this for see taken time https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode

Comment: @Larme yes its improved by few seconds but still taking much time than expected.

Comment: @Mats i also checked with Profiler its showing around 30-40 seconds.

Comment: Are you building in Debug or Release mode? You should always do benchmarking in Release mode, as you'll have optimisations enabled.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for benchmarking purposes? For now, all I can do is guess which part takes time

Comment: @CodeDifferent Here is example data [
 {
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "Bertha Hamilton",
  "Producer_ID": "VBI09ROA3ZG",
  "Status": "Hymenaeos Mauris Associates",
  "Start_Date": "2014-10-26 19:57:12",
  "Requested_By": "semper@elit.org",
  "State": "SU",
  "Region": "Limburg",
  "Trip_Type": "libero. Donec consectetuer mauris id sapien. Cras dolor dolor, tempus",
  "Visitor1": "Allen",
  "Visitor2": "Amy",
  "Visitor3": "Hedwig",
  "Visitor4": "Travis Campbell",
  "Visitor5": "Gemma Q. Collins",
  "Visitor6": "Violet"
 }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main performance issue with your sort is that you perform the transformations in the comparison closure.  This will call the value formatting process an exponential number of times (based on the size of the array).

A more efficient way of doing this would be to perform the transformations only once using .map() and apply the sort function to the result.

Here is an example based on your code using a function to extract the sort values and .map() to perform this extraction only once per element in the array:

```
// only initialize your date formatter once
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"

// Extract the appropriate value and returns it in one of 3 types
// sorting will compare the 3 typed values knowing that only one of the 3
// will actually differ for a given data type
// 
// The element is returned in the tupple in order to rebuild the
// array content after sorting on the 3 values
func getSortValues(_ element:[String:Any], _ id:String) -> ([String:Any], String, Int, TimeInterval)
{
    let value          = element[id]
    var stringOrder    = ""
    var numericOrder   = 0
    var dateOrder      = TimeInterval(0)

    if let stringValue = value as? String,
       let dateValue   = dateFormatter.date(from:stringValue)   
    { 
      dateOrder = dateValue.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate 
    }
    else if let intValue = value as? Int
    {
      numericOrder     = intValue
    }
    else if value != nil
    {
      stringOrder  = "\(value!)"  
    }
    return (element, stringOrder, numericOrder, dateOrder)
}

let columnId = headers![b.tag - 10]
fd = fd!.map{ getSortValues($0, columnId) } 
        .sorted{ $0.1 < $1.1 || $0.2 < $1.2 || $0.3 < $1.3 }
        .map{ $0.0 }
```

It should go anywhere from 10 to 30 times faster (depending on the size of the array).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and will confirm if it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Its working good. although still little slow but improved definitely.

Comment: The remaining bottleneck is the dynamic determination of the value type.  Using the date formatter to determine if strings actually contain a date will slow thing down for all columns (where only date columns would actually need it).  You could further optimize this by associating a specialized sort function to your headers based on the type of data you expect to have in the corresponding column.  Even the date sort could benefit from an additional (faster) test to determine if the string is likely to contain a date (avoiding the overhead of the date formatter)

Comment: Thanks. will check that. once i get it, i will update it here.